# SKLearn MLPClassifier import error

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm unable to import `MLPClassifier` from `SKLearn`.
The version is 0.17
This is the error I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MLPClassifier
```

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

I have the latest version of SKLearn I installed. I also updated it using:
pip install -U scikit-learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sklearn.neural_network` in version 0.17 has only the `BernoulliRBM` class as shown on the [version page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.neural_network). You can confirm this by doing:

```
>>> from sklearn import neural_network
>>> getattr(neural_network, "MLPCLassifier", None)
>>> getattr(neural_network, "BernoulliRBM", None)
<class 'sklearn.neural_network.rbm.BernoulliRBM'>
```

You can install directly from `git` to get the version 0.18 which has the `MLPCLassifier` class:

```
$ pip install cython
$ pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

`cython` is required to *cythonize* your installation.

Comment: Is there a better Neural Networks library for supervised learning?

Comment: Try keras (easiest), lasagne (less theano abstraction than keras), tensorflow... (there are a lot general NN-libs). They will be much faster and support way more features! From sklearn-docs: ```Warning This implementation is not intended for large-scale applications. In particular, scikit-learn offers no GPU support. For much faster, GPU-based implementations, as well as frameworks offering much more flexibility to build deep learning architectures, see Related Projects.``` The link to related projects: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/related_projects.html#related-projects)

Answer (score 0):

### Run the below command. This will uninstall the older version and re install the updated version.

### pip install -U scikit-learn

The message below will appear after installation.

DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scikit-learn) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.

```
Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.14.1:
  Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.14.1
```

Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.19.1